# Find duplicate row in a result query in php

Tags: php

I want to have the duplicate of this table if all the columns in the table are the same without the `id_import`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_import] => 209
            [date] => 2018-08-14
            [id_account] => 4090
            [id_property] => 18
            [method] => accounting
            [type] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_import] => 209
            [date] => 2018-08-14
            [id_account] => 4091
            [id_property] => 18
            [method] => accounting
            [type] => 0
        )

   .....
)
```

I want to loop on every array from this big array and return duplicates with this condition:

`date`, `id_account`, `id_property`, `method`, `type` are the same and only id_import is the different one

Example:

```
[id_import] => 208
[date] => 2018-08-14
[id_account] => 4090
[id_property] => 18
[method] => accounting
[type] => 0

[id_import] => 209
[date] => 2018-08-14
[id_account] => 4090
[id_property] => 18
[method] => accounting
[type] => 0
```

In this example it should be considered as a duplicate, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post what code you have written thus far and describe what doesn't work. Please also read [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Make an associative array whose keys are the concatenation of all the other values.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think you should iterate on every list and check if there is an element equal to what you're looking for, but this is gonna cost you a lot of time if you have too long data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say that you have an array called `$array` this would be the answer you're looking for :

```
foreach ($array as $current_key => $current_array) {
    foreach ($array as $search_key => $search_array) {
        if (
            $search_array["date"] == $current_array["date"] &&
            $search_array["id_account"] == $current_array["id_account"] &&
            $search_array["id_property"] == $current_array["id_property"] &&
            $search_array["method"] == $current_array["method"] &&
            $search_array["type"] == $current_array["type"] &&
            $search_array["id_import"] != $current_array["id_import"]
        ) {
            if ($search_key != $current_key) {
                echo "duplicate found: $search_key,$current_key\n";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

this will find you duplicates in your array taking in consideration : everything should be the same except for `id_import` it should be different